# Store data using modal and pass $id variable

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

**I want to pass the variable id from `(the url is /xxxx/{{id}} )` to store**

I have a modal box which opens a form. This info is then stored using the controller shown below:

I tried adding `$id` to pass through the controller `(the url is /xxxx/{{id}} )`

**OpenHome Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)

    $option = new Option;
    $option->time = $request->input('time');
    $option->date = $request->input('date');
    $option->save();
    return view('option.create');
```

> ERROR: Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\option::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

**dd($request->all());**

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "7O23EkldYOYj1d7Fc2xNflcPWMY67ytGTkrymy9g"
  "time" => "00:12"
  "date" => "12-05-1996"
]
```

Comment: can you please show your route?

Comment: try dd($request->all());  and show me output

Comment: Your method is now expecting two parameters, and you call it using only one. That's what the error message says.

Comment: @SachinAghera done

Comment: @kerbholz yup im trying to find a way to pass $id

Comment: now you wan to save id also?

Comment: @SachinAghera yes

Comment: in route file it is post call or get call?

Comment: @SachinAghera POST

Comment: your route url is just like url is /xxxx/{id} ....not double bracket

Answer (score 0):

In your question you imply an update of an existing record, but in your code it implies the creation of a new option.

If you wanted to update an option with the `$id = 1` you need to have the following route.

```
Route::put('/options/{id}', 'OptionController@update');
```

Inside your controller.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $option = Option::find($id);
  $option->update([
    'time' => $request->input('time'),
    'date' => $request->input('date'),
  ]);

  // Redirect to display the list of options.
  return redirect('/options'); 
}
```

However if you just wanted to pass an additional variable to the store method for use inside the store method, make sure the `Route` only  has single set of `{}` around the variable.

```
Route::post('/option/{variable}', 'OptionController@store');

public function store(Request $request, $variable)
{
  // User the $variable passed as a route parameter.
}
```